# Can 'SET' command be used along with Select query in PREPARE statement in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgreqSql. I am trying to have a parameter set at session level. Since there is already an existing PREPARE statement, can "SET" command be included as part of the PREPARE statement along with a select query.

Current Prepare statement is:

```
set pSqlStmt  "PREPARE check ( \
             bigint, \
             character varying(32), \
             character varying(64)) \
                 AS \
             SELECT E.ID, E.NUMBER      \
                         FROM EMPLOYEE E, APPKEY S      \
                         WHERE E.STATE != 1            \
                         AND E.ID != \$1              \
                         AND E.TYPE = \$2        \
                         AND S.ID = E.ID  AND S.KEYNAME = \'ABCD\' \
                         AND S.KEYVALUE = \$3"
```

In this prepare statement, can a set command say:

```
Set enable_seqscan=on;
```

(just a sample).
Can be used?

Answer (score 0):

The query optimizer parameters you set will only have an impact when the query is planned.

By default, this always happens for the first five executions of the query. After that, PostgreSQL may choose to use a “generic plan” that is independent of the parameter values. It does that if it expects no performance degradation from that.

So the parameter values at the time you prepare the statement are irrelevant. The parameters are relevant for those executions that generate an execution plan. Once PostgreSQL starts using a generic plan, that plan will be immune to changes of optimizer parameters. But if PostgreSQL chooses not to use a generic plan, or during the first few executions of the statement, the values of optimizer parameters will influence the plan chosen.